# Jenkins: a heavily branched chain of build jobs

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, docker, jenkins-workflow

We would like to set up Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment processes on the base of `Jenkins` ecosystem. Currently we're trying to put together all the `Jenkins` build jobs we have (from sources to several endpoint processes launched on the testing server). There are three kinds of build/deployment processes in our case:

1. Building `deb` packages from `C++` projects (some of them are *dependent*, others are *dependencies*);
2. Building images from `Docker` containers;
3. Launching some processes in the endpoint;

[image]

As you can notice, we faced with a heavily branched chain of jobs triggered by each other. And every update of any of the upstream projects must go throughout the chain of jobs and trigger the final job (`process I`). So It would be nice to use some kind of `Jenkins` plugins that will:

- Control such a complicated structure of jobs (I tried to use [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) and I got the impression that this tool is suitable for "linear" job chain);
- Provide clean way of passing the parameters between job environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for passing parameters, you should be using **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**.

For a more asynchronous passing of parameters, you an use **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** (it's extremely useful and flexible for all sorts of things, and considering your complexity, might prove useful regardless if you use it for passing parameters or not)

As for control, research into **[Workflow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin)**. It allows to write the whole execution flow in it's own Groovy script, with fine granular control. More links:
Official - https://jenkins-ci.org/content/workflow-plugin-10
Tutorial - https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/c15589f/TUTORIAL.md#pausing-flyweight-vs-heavyweight-executors

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply! I've read about `Gradle`. How do you think, isn't it more suitable for this case?

Comment: Don't have experience with Gradle, so can't comment. I was under the impression that it's just a build system, whereas Jenkins is the whole package, with monitoring, notification, archiving and control. Jenkins has plugins to enable Gradle build steps.

Answer (score 3):

As @slav mentioned, the Workflow plugin should be able to handle this kind of complex control flow, including parallel handling of subtasks, simple handling of variables throughout the process (would just be Groovy local variables), and [Docker support](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Workflow+Plugin).

You could of course arrange this whole process in a single `build.gradle` (or `Makefile` for that matter). That would be suitable if you did not mind running all the steps on the same Jenkins slave, and did not otherwise need to interact with or report to Jenkins in any particular way in the middle of the build.